# Can't create a phylum tree using bio pythons TreeConstruction tool module

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

Trying to create a basic phylum tree using biopython, specifically following this documentation page https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Phylo.TreeConstruction.DistanceTreeConstructor-class.html. Every time I do use fastfa files I seem to get an error.

```
from Bio.Phylo.TreeConstruction import DistanceCalculator
aln = AlignIO.read("canine.fasta", 'fasta')
constructor = DistanceTreeConstructor()
calculator = DistanceCalculator('identity')
dm = calculator.get_distance(aln)
upgmatree = constructor.upgma(dm)
print(upmgmatree)
```

The error I get:

```
  File "/Users/theodorelatimer/Desktop/Interna Assment HL Biology/Bio IA.py", line 36, in <module>
    upgmatree = constructor.upgma(dm)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Bio/Phylo/TreeConstruction.py", line 696, in upgma
    inner_clade.branch_length = 0
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'inner_clade' referenced before assignment
```

my goal is to be able to generate any kind of phylum tree with multiple protein sequences. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've also tried to add more protein sequences to the align variable but that seems to give me the same issue involving inner clades.

I know in the documentation I linked phylip was used but I'm unsure how to make a sequence alignment with that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the source for `upgma()`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/0ed5f25b2b4296161eeb3139d23d9549d89cfa75/Bio/Phylo/TreeConstruction.py#L631), the only way you can hit a case where `inner_clade` has not been assigned is that the distance matrix you pass in is empty or length 1.

If you print out `dm`, is that the case? If so, you'll probably have to figure out why.

Comment: when I print out dm I get ```tr|E2RKZ5|E2RKZ5_CANLF 0
 tr|E2RKZ5|E2RKZ5_CANLF```

Comment: Looks like there's only one row alright. Check your input data, etc.